# Trouble Modifying Memory in QEMU Device Module using GDB

Tags: c, gdb, qemu

I'm working on a QEMU project involving a device module with read and write functions (`dummy_read` and `dummy_write`). The memory address in question is `0x916e000`, and I've set up the `MemoryRegionOps` structure (`dummy_ops`) with appropriate callbacks.

Reading the memory using `"x/x 0x916e000"` in GDB works fine, but modifying it with `"set {int}0x916e000=0x1"` does not have the desired effect.

A snippet from the device module code is as follows;

```c
static uint64_t dummy_read(void *opaque, hwaddr addr, unsigned size)
{
    printf("dummy_read\n");
    
    return 0;
}

static void dummy_write(void *opaque, hwaddr addr, uint64_t val, 
                              unsigned size)
{
    printf("dummy_write\n");
}

static const MemoryRegionOps dummy_ops = {
    .read = dummy_read,
    .write = dummy_write,
    .valid.min_access_size = 1,
    .valid.max_access_size = 8,
    .valid.unaligned = true,
    .endianness = DEVICE_NATIVE_ENDIAN,
};
```

Here are some points I've considered:

1. The memory address is valid and corresponds to the device module.
2. The write callback (`dummy_write`) suggests that the region should be writable.
3. The syntax of the `set` command seems correct.
4. QEMU is in a state allowing memory modifications.

Additional details:

- I've observed that I can successfully invoke the `dummy_write()` function of the device module using the `writeReg()` function in the application code running on the QEMU machine. Here's a snippet of the application code:

```c
void writeReg(uint32_t addr, uint32_t data)
{
    uint32_t *ptr = (uint32_t *)addr;
    *ptr = data;
}

int main()
{
    writeReg(0x916e000, 0x1);
    // Successfully invokes dummy_write() function

    return 0;
}
```

Despite being able to write to the memory area of the device module with the application code, I encounter issues when trying to achieve the same with the `set` command in the GDB session.

Is there anything specific I might be missing or any additional steps I should take to troubleshoot and successfully modify the memory at this address within the QEMU environment using GDB?

Your insights and suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you!